# How can I find the multiplicative inverse of $7 \pmod{15}$?

Tags: inverse, euclidean-algorithm

I tried, although didn't succeed. I got to the point where I have got $15 = 7  \cdot 2 + 1$. And then I have rearranged this for $1$.

In addition, is there a general way to solve these?

Thanks.

Comment: "*Is there a general way to solve these?*"  Yes, to find the inverse of $a$ mod $b$ use the extended euclidean division algorithm to find $x$ and $y$ so that $ax+by=\gcd(a,b)$.  Assuming $a$ is relatively prime to $b$, you can rearrange this in the correct way to get what you want.

Answer (score 7):

If you know $$15=7(2)+1$$

Let's consider $\mod 15$

$$0\equiv7(2)+1 \mod 15$$

$$7(-2) \equiv 1 \mod 15$$

Hence $$(13)7\equiv 1 \mod 15$$

Comment: how did you get that last step

Comment: $$-2 \equiv 13 \mod 15$$

Comment: ah i see! thank you :)

Comment: I really don't understand the last line?

Comment: If $-2 \equiv 13 \mod 15$, we have $(-2)7 \equiv 13(7) \mod 15$ right?